# Statistical test to know if there is a significant difference between 2 different time series models

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Imagine that I am doing a Rolling Forecast on a time series. I use the same data for model 1 and model 2 (e.g. model 1 ARIMA, model 2 HoltWinter Expo smoothing).

To measure quality I use the sMAPE.

However, I would like to know if there is a statistical test to determine whether one model is better than another. **Is that possible?**

To illustrate the problem, imagine Scenario 1:

- Model 1 gives a sMAPE of 2.2
- Model 2 gives a sMAPE of 5.5

Now, imagine Scenario 2:

- Model 1 gives a sMAPE of 2.2
- Model 2 gives a sMAPE of 2.22

Intuitively, one may wonder whether model 1 in scenario 2 is really better than model 2. It may be that if new data are used in the future, model 2 will give a better (or identical sMAPE...).   However, for scenario 1 it seems obvious that model 1 is significantly better than model 2. [However, I am not sure that such comments are credible in a scientific article. This is why I look for a statistical test].

PS: I mention sMAPE as a measure, but of course I am also ready to perform a test with the predicted data (yhat) and the actual data (y) instead of sMAPE.

PS2: I use different models, some are from statistical field (e.g. ARIMA) and others are from machine learning field (e.g. random forest...)

PS3: I would like to make it clear that I am not a statistician or mathematician. I prefer to clarify this in case my question seems somewhat strange to the experts in the field.

Comment: Looking at it from a somewhat different perspective, you might want to check out the diebold-mariano test. if you google, a lot of things will come up but it's probably best to read their original paper. then, after that, read the "20 ( may not be 20 ) years after the diebold-mariano test" by the same authors. I'll try to find links for them and send them in a follow up comment.

Comment: This is the 20 year one. https://www.sas.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/papers/paper113/Diebold_DM%20Test.pdf  This is the original. https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07350015.1995.10524599#.XUD40WQpDcs

Comment: Hello thank you for your feedback. I think your comment can be passed on as an answer since the test you are proposing is exactly what I am looking for. 

I found a version of the test on Python https://github.com/johntwk/Diebold-Mariano-Test
There is also a version R on the forecast package.

Comment: There is nevertheless a parameter that both Python and R implementations disturb me. It is the fact of giving a forecast horizon h. For example, if I give a vector of 120 forecasts from model 1 and model 2, it seems obvious to me that the forecast horizon is 120. Why would one give a smaller forecast horizon?

Comment: Hi: the horizon denotes how far out you are forecasting. So, if you're forecast is for  time t+h and you're currently at time t, then the horizon is h. be sure to read the paper carefully ( along with the 20 year recap ) because diebold mentiions ( in the second one ) that are many people that have interpreted the test incorrectly. it's deceptively complicated material. if it's an answer, I'm glad it helped.